# Copy & paste between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

**I try to achieve the following**:

- I have one master table in a worksheet
- And an identical table in another worksheet
- If a cell in the master sheet table is empty, the code should check the corresponding cell in the other worksheet table
- If the corresponding cell contains a value, this value should be copied to the empty cell of the master sheet table

  - This should be repeated for all cells in the master sheet table

So far I have found only one useful code which might be adjusted for my purpose. Unfortunately, the below code as it is now copies all values from the other sheet table to the master sheet table without checking if the master sheet already contains values in the respective cells. So it overwrites all given values in the master sheet table which I do not want. The code has some message boxes in German. Please ignore these, as they are not relevant. Many thanks!:

Sub VorDatenKopieren()

```
    asi = ActiveSheet.Index
    nasi = Sheets(asi).Name

    If asi = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Zu " & nasi & " gibt es keine vorherige Tabelle!", _
               48, Environ("UserName")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    asiv = ActiveSheet.Index - 1
    nasiv = Sheets(asiv).Name
    mgb = MsgBox("Daten werden kopiert von " & nasiv & " nach " & nasi & Chr(13) & _
                 "Ist das OK?", 36, Environ("UserName"))
    If mgb = 7 Then Exit Sub                     ' 7 = nein
    Sheets(asiv).Select
    Range("c3:g17").Copy
    Sheets(asi).Select
    Range("c3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                             :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry - reformatted your code and can't get the procedure name to stay on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Darren,
there is an option to paste values without blanks with using *SkipBlanks = True*:

```
Range("c3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                             :=True, Transpose:=False
```

So maybe you should copy table from master sheet to another worksheet without blanks and then copy the whole table from another sheet to master? It should solve your problem.

```
Sheets(asi).Select
Range("c3:g17").Copy
Sheets(asiv).Select
Range("c3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                             :=True, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Hi Michal, I tested this, but it does not do the trick. The problem is that given values in the master sheet table are being overwritten.

Comment: Hi all, anybody with an idea?